# Tutorial para enviar ArrayList<String> como JSON en Adroid con AsynTask

Tags: php, json, android-asynctask

Estoy buscando un tutorial o ejemplo de como pasar un ArrayList a JSON y enviarlo a través de un AsynTask a un servidor PHP, pero no veo nada claro. Tenéis algún link de algún tutorial bueno o algún código ya picado por ahí?

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida, aunque interesante tu pregunta pudiera terminar cerrada ya que es amplia y basada en opiniones; toda vez que esta comunidad es para resolver problemas concretos de programación, tienes la suficiente reputación para entrar al [chat] y ahi seguro alguien te auxiliará

Comment: Gracias @AlfredoPaz, siento haber molestado

Comment: no molestas, te invito al chat y colocar tu duda ahi, todos los participantes son bienvenidos y bienvenidas solo que hay ciertos puntos que de seguirlos te harán mas fácil obtener ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para la primera inquietud sobre como pasar un de arraylist a json puedes usar la libreria Gson un ejemplo de este seria:

```
Gson gsonTemp = new Gson();
String stringArrayList = gsonTemp.toJson(myArray);
```

por si algun motivo deseas algo mas manual puedes recorrer los string del arraylist y pasarlos a la variable JSONArray:

```
JSONArray myJsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0 ; i < myArray.size() ; i++){
myJsonArray.put(myArray.get(i));
}
```

para la cuestion de enviar el json en el asynctask yo te sugiero usar HttpURLConnection

```
URL miurl = new URL("www.midominio.com/api/mifuncion.php");
HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) miurl.openConnection();
myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // si es POST y si es GET pues pones GET
myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json");

DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(myConnection.getOutputStream());
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(myJsonArray.toString());
dataOutputStream.flush();
dataOutputStream.close();

int codigoRespuesta = myConnection.getResponseCode();
Log.i("algunTAG","Server Respondio: "+codigoRespuesta);
Log.i("algunTAG","mensaje : --> "+myConnection.getResponseMessage());
```

saludos y buena energia :)
mi referencia es esta: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero responder preguntas que están realizadas sin seguir lo definido en [ask] provoca que el sitio tenga contenido de baja calidad, ayúdanos a orientar al OP a crear preguntas de buena calidad que sean útiles para toda la comunidad.

Comment: huy, que pena. lo siento, sigo en el aprendisaje de como interactuar de manera correcta en la pagina :), debo eliminar mi respuesta? saludos!

Comment: No, ya que el OP la marco como aceptada pero lo que requiere en realidad es un tutorial. Revisa las causas por las que puede ser cerrada una pregunta que no cumple con lo definido en [help] : https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions Es imporante que el usuario que pregunta debe mostrar de preferencia lo que ha investigado o tratado, esto nos beneficia como comunidad.